# Div not coming to front: Z-Index

Tags: css, z-index

I am using the code below, but `.under` is not rising above (and covering up) `#portfolio_content .img img` as it should on `hover`.

```
#portfolio_wrap {
    overflow:hidden;
    width:980px;
    float:left
}
#portfolio_content {
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    margin:0 auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:650px!important
}
#portfolio_content ul {
    list-style:none
}
#portfolio_content .img a { }
#portfolio_content .img a:hover { }
#portfolio_content .img {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    height:210px;
    margin:0 35px 35px 0!important;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:0;
    width:307px
}
#portfolio_content .img img {
    display:block;
    position:absolute!important;
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index:3!important
}
#portfolio_content .img .title, #portfolio_content .img .title a {
    font-size:22px;
    margin:100px 0 10px 0;
    float:left!important;
    width:307px;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative
}
.desc {
    font-size:13px;
    display:block;
    text-align:center!important;
    margin:0 auto!important;
    width:307px
}
.under {
    z-index:2!important;
    display:inline;
    position:absolute;
    width:307px;
    height:210px
}
.under:hover { z-index:4!important }
```

Any thoughts? I am assuming this is related to z-index, but I don't know what I have done wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I saw that it wasn't the case=)

Comment: Could you post your HTML? Thx.

Comment: Creating a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) may be helpful.

Comment: After seeing your jsFiddle, I'd say @tw16's answer is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing the page rendered, I would have to assume the problem is that you cannot actually hover over `.under` (`z-index:2`) as it is hidden under the `#portfolio_content .img img` (`z-index:3`) initially and therefore you would just be hovering the `img` instead.

Comment: also id class element is a higher specifity than class, idk if @tw16 is saying that too, but that is going to override a simple class declaration

Answer (score 1):

You cannot hover over `.under` since it's always "under" your images, tw16 is right.

Instead of playing with z-indexes, try actually placing `.under` inside `.img` but on top of your images and with `display:none`, and then do something like :

```
.img:hover .under{
    display:block;
}
```

I might add your markup isn't quite optimized and `.img` should be directly placed on the `a` tags, not on useless inside `span`s, which are waaaay too many anyway :)

**Edit :** (as answer to comment)

In case there is no image to show, your markup will be different (as i suppose generated by a server side script, like php) as when there is one to display (for instance you won't echo the `img` tag).
You can as well use that condition to write 2 differents classes, for instance `.img` and `.no-img` :

```
.no-img .under{
    display:block;
}

.img .under{
    display:none;
}

.img:hover .under{
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is I still need the titles to display when there isn't an image ( http://themeforward.com/demo2/portfolio/ ).  Thanks for pointing out the spans though, fixing it.